# Can't get pspell to work

Tags: nginx, centos6, php-fpm, php

I installed aspell\pspell, and if I do

```
> aspell dump dicts
ar
cs
de
de_AT
de_CH
de_DE
en
en-variant_0
en-variant_1
en-variant_2
en-w_accents
en-wo_accents
en_CA
en_CA-variant_0
en_CA-variant_1
en_CA-w_accents
en_CA-wo_accents
en_GB
en_GB-ise
en_GB-ise-w_accents
en_GB-ise-wo_accents
en_GB-ize
en_GB-ize-w_accents
en_GB-ize-wo_accents
en_GB-variant_0
en_GB-variant_1
en_GB-w_accents
en_GB-wo_accents
en_US
en_US-variant_0
en_US-variant_1
en_US-w_accents
en_US-wo_accents
es
fr-40
fr-60
fr
fr-80
fr-lrg
fr-med
fr-sml
fr_CH-40
fr_CH-60
fr_CH
fr_CH-80
fr_CH-lrg
fr_CH-med
fr_CH-sml
fr_FR-40
fr_FR
fr_FR-60
fr_FR-80
fr_FR-lrg
fr_FR-med
fr_FR-sml
pt_BR
pt_PT
ro
ro-classic
ru
ru-ye
ru-yeyo
ru-yo
sv
tr
```

Yet, when I run this simple script:

```
 <?php
$dict = pspell_new ("en");
if (!pspell_check ($dict, "carr")) {
    $suggestions = pspell_suggest ($dict, "carr");
     foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) {
        echo "Did you mean: $suggestion?<br />";
     }
}
?>
```

I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  pspell_new(): PSPELL couldn't open the dictionary.
>   reason: No word lists can be found for the language "en". in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/t.php on line 2

I'm sure aspell is correctly installed, also on phpinfo() it says pspell is enabled
I think php is searching for the dictionaries in the wrong directory. Is there any way to know in which directory?

Comment: Check your error log, or try running the code from the command line.

Comment: I'm running it from the command-line. Going crazy. Already installed with yum, built it from source (several versions)... nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running PHP/Aspell code. I have no experience with PHP/Aspell. However I did assemble some Aspell code in Perl and Ruby and thus owns some experience with. Your PHP/Aspell problem looks at first glance an Aspell configuration issue. Provided this URL link (the Perl/Aspell one) at http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/Linux-Windows-Perl-Aspell-Determining_the_country_of_a_Web_query.html is of any help to you then I should be glad. If you keep very curious and open minded with, you may refer yourself to the Ruby/Aspell equivalent of the Perl code at http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/Linux-Ruby-Aspell-Determining_the_country_of_a_Web_query.html. This Ruby/Aspell work had the sole intent to compare Ruby and Perl performances on an identical algorithm both based onto an Aspell solution.

Yours truly,
Philippe